# How to substract 2 varchar dates in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these varchar : 20211026231735.

So I would like a query to substract actual sysdate to that date and convert the substraction to DAY HOURS AND SECONDS.

```
select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') - start_time from TABLEA where job_name='jOB_AA_BB';
I get 4220.
```

Any help please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you do datetime arithmetic with the `DATE` datatype, you get back a `NUMBER` of days. To get an `INTERVAL` you can subtract two `TIMESTAMPs`. You don't say what the data type is for start_time, but you might get away with this:

```
select localtimestamp - start_time 
from tablea where job_name='jOB_AA_BB';
```

`LOCALTIMESTAMP` gives you a `TIMESTAMP` value in the current session time zone. There's also `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, which give you the same thing in a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and `SYSTIMESTAMP` that gives you the database time in `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. You may need to convert your `start_time` to avoid time zone differences, if any.

Comment: Start_time data_type is varchar2. When I do your query it gives me error: ORA-1841

Comment: Then you need to convert it to a timestamp with `to_timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can us the function  [numtodsinterval](https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/datetime-functions/oracle-numtodsinterval-function.php) to convert the results of date arithmetic to an interval. If necessary then use [extract](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-date-functions/oracle-extract/) to pull out the needed components.

```
with tablea(job_name, start_time) as 
     (select 'jOB_AA_BB','20211026231735' from dual)
select numtodsinterval((SYSDATE - to_date( start_time,'yyyymmddhh24miss')),'hour') date_diff
 from tablea where job_name='jOB_AA_BB' ;

with tablea(job_name, start_time) as 
     (select 'jOB_AA_BB','20211026231735' from dual) 
select extract (hour from date_diff) || ':' || extract (minute from date_diff)
  from ( 
         select numtodsinterval((sysdate - to_date( start_time,'yyyymmddhh24miss')),'day') date_diff
           from tablea where job_name='jOB_AA_BB' 
       );
```

NOTE: I am not sure how you got any result, other than an error, as your query winds up as `a string - a string`. You should not convert sysdate to a string but your string to a date (better yet store it as the proper data type - **date**).

Comment: Don't works, the substraction is bad. If I do now query  select sysdate from dual it gives me 27-OCT-21 11:29:32. If I do your first sentence gives me value : 0 0:5:32.41666667. But  that's not correct

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the value to a date (rather than converting `SYSDATE` to a string) and then subtract and explicitly return the value as an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` type:

```sql
SELECT (SYSDATE - TO_DATE('20211026231735', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) DAY TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL;
```

Or, for your table:

```sql
SELECT (SYSDATE - TO_DATE(start_time,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) DAY(5) TO SECOND
FROM   TABLEA
WHERE  job_name='jOB_AA_BB';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1bec4179bcf5c08d7b266451210ca4dd)*

Comment: It gives me error ORA-01873

Comment: @defekas17 Then you can increase the leading precision (the number of digits for the days) of the interval by adding that to the query.